# Solving some geometry problems using involutions

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

Some geometry problems ( like [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=38178) and [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=17) ) have short solutions if we use involutions. What references are there for solving geometry problems using involutions? I am particularly interested in theoretical aspects of involutions, and maybe a reference with solved problems like these two presented in the links.